How to render large static text in react component
I'm working on a large reactjs project and now in my final stages, I need to implement a few static pages: Accessibility Management, Privacy Policy, Shipping and Refund Policy, and maybe a few more.
These pages are a very simple pages that will include mostly static text that won't be changed often.
Of each document, I have a translated version for 5 languages.
I was wondering what is the correct way for implementing these pages, taking in considiration a few things:

When one of these pages are visited and only in that case, I want to load the relevent text. So only one file is loaded only when needed.
The text has a title that need to be wrapped in h4 tag, few headlines that is wrapped in h6 tags, and few text contents that is wrapped in <b> tags.

What solution I thought of:

I need to decide where to store these content, and for - semplicity, because the content of the files are static, and to get advantage of caching - I decided to store it in the frontend, maybe in /public folder.
I need to decide in which format I want to store these content, and the bests format I found is txt, because these pages will include lots of text, and because the content structure is predefined with tags.
Because I'm using i18n for handling the translation of strings in my project, I thought to use it for this manner too. But I figured out quickly that although it handles json pretty good, it isn't easy and straight forward to handle txt files with lots of paragraphs structure.
Take advantage of dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }} somehow

What is the best practice of storing these files, loading one when needed and render it with its pre-defined format?
PS - I know how:

Get the current language from the user through i18n
Decide which file content I need through ROUTE
Construct the styled component that renders the content in react

